# Use MSBuild to define SSRS projects RDL Schema version

Tags: jenkins, reporting-services, msbuild, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I am working on a Continuous Integration project that builds a Microsoft SSRS solution. However the RDL files produced are not always of the same schema version, some of them appear in 2008 format, and others in 2010 etc as per the following:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

Others appear like

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

I have a Build.proj file that is responsible for performing an MSBuild on the .sln files, and looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project DefaultTarget="Compile" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

  <Target Name="Compile">

    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(BuildDirectory)\ReportsPrimary.sln"
      Properties="Configuration=$(Environment)"
    />

    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(BuildDirectory)\ReportsSecondary.sln"
      Properties="Configuration=$(Environment)"
    />

    <MSBuild
          Projects="$(BuildDirectory)\ReportsSpecial.sln"
          Properties="Configuration=$(Environment)"
    />

  </Target>

</Project>
```

I need a means of enforcing that the RDL schema produced from the build is the 2008 version. Is it possible to perform some configuration inside my Build.proj file so that the RDL format will adhere to the 2008 schema version?

If not how else can I achieve the same functionality? Any recommendations? CI is relatively new to me

Thanks all!

Comment: @R.Richards I have deleted that post and replaced it with this one.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild does not support reporting projects and will not transform the RDL files into the correct format.

You can use the Visual Studio mechanism to build a SSRS project.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
"MyReportingProjPath\MyReportingProj.sln" /build release
```

Update your report with the creaded RDL files.

https://blogs.infosupport.com/managing-ssrs-reports-with-powershell/